# BeanCreationException:Error creating bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

## mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean class="com.springframework.BlogController">
<property name="formView" value="Welcome" />
<property name="successView" value="Home" />

<!-- Mapping validator -->
<property name="validator">
    <bean class="com.springframework.BloggerValidator" />
</property>
```

## Error:

SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.springframework.BlogController] for bean with name 'com.springframework.BlogController#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springframework.BlogController
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.springframework.BlogController] for bean with name 'com.springframework.BlogController#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springframework.BlogController
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: Is the class BlogController in a jar?

Comment: No. BlogController is present in the package com.springframework

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot find class [com.springframework.BlogController] for bean with name 'com.springframework.BlogController'

No class called com.springframework.BlogController on your webapp's classpath.

Check if the qualified classname is correct in /WEB-INF/"*".xml

Or, check if /WEB-INF/classes directory in missing.

Comment: The class BlogController is present in its location, also the name is specified correctly in my xml file.